# java.lang package in java

Tags: java, lang

Since `java.lang` package is automatically imported in all java programs by compiler, why is it necessary to write `import java.lang.annotation;` statement at the top of the program while using annotations in the program?

Answer (score 5):

Because the `java.lang.annotation` package isn't the same as the `java.lang` package. They're simply different packages.

Imagine if importing one package imported all the packages "under" it - then

```
import java.*;
```

would import almost everything in the standard libraries - but that's not the way it works. An import statement of

```
import foo.*;
```

simply imports all the types in the `foo` package - it doesn't import anything in any other packages which happen to start with `foo.`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `java.lang` automatic import is just for it's classes and interfaces whose package belong it is `java.lang`.

`annotation` is a sub-package inside `java.lang` and this automatic behaviors don't propagate to sub-package only immediate classes of `java.lang`

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)